# Why does list_add_rcu only protect "prev->next"?

Tags: linux-kernel, locking, rcu

Following is the implementation of `__list_add_rcu` in [include/linux/rculist.h](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/rculist.h):

```c
static inline void __list_add_rcu(struct list_head *new,
        struct list_head *prev, struct list_head *next)
{
    new->next = next;
    new->prev = prev;
    rcu_assign_pointer(list_next_rcu(prev), new);
    next->prev = new;
}
```

Inside the function body, *rcu-lock* protects the update of `prev->next`, but no protection on `next->prev`. Why? Did I miss anything obvious here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

RCU-lock **is unable to garantee correctness of traversing list in both directions**.

In short, such garantee would require to "protect" two pointers(`next->prev` and `prev->next`) *at once*.  But **RCU-section is not an exclusive section**, so it is possible for two pointers to have values inconsistent between themselves.

Because of that, **RCU garantees correctness only for forward list traversal**. For doing that, it is sufficient to protect only `prev->next`.

*Hint*: While there are macros for reverse list traversal (such as `list_for_each_entry_reverse`), such macros have no RCU counterpairs. This is just because RCU doesn't support such traversal type.